# truffle: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

My config:

```
module.exports = {   networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }   } };
```

My geth running on the same port:

```
C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\Mist\binaries\Geth\unpacked\geth.exe --testnet --fast --ipcpath \\.\pipe\geth.ipc --rpccorsdomain * --rpcport 8545
I use Geth/v1.6.6-stable-10a45cb5/windows-amd64/go1.8.3
```

I am running

```
C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\Mist\binaries\Geth\unpacked\geth.exe attach
```

What's wrong?

I tried all other recipes from 'Invalid JSON' qiestions here on this site nothing helps.

Comment: Try enabling rpc with in geth command line `--rpc --rpcapi eth,web3,net,personal,ssh,db,debug`.

Comment: Same story with this parameters.